# Prism DialogService Show MODAL dialog

Tags: c#, xamarin, xamarin.forms, prism

I am using Prism IDialogService to popup a screen that ask  some  complementary information and validations, before decide to sabe or not to sabe, my problem is when I do

```
        _dialogService.ShowDialog("InconsistenciasDialog", param, CloseDialogCallbackAsync);
        if (allDataFill)
            saveAll();
```

In the CloseDialogCallbackAsync  Method I set a property 'allDataFill' in order to know if the dialog gets all the Infformation I need, thats way I need the dialog as a modal and sincronus one.

The dialog shows up, but  not in a sincronous way, inmediatly test the variable allDataFill and thats a problem, because that variable isn't with data yet.

Thats way I need a modal dialog, it is posible witth DialogService?

Any Idea?

Comment: You want to check the data is fill or not before close the dialog? Or you don't want user to close the dialog until the data loaded completely?

Answer (score 1):

You have to `await` the AsyncCallback Method.

Answer (score 0):

`IDialogService.ShowDialog` *does* show a modal dialog, and the callback will be called when the dialog is closed.

You can use `Show` if you want it to be non-modal.